# Does the verb "esquisser" mean anything in Latex terminology?

Tags: macros

Latex doesn't want me to write "esquisser". Does that mean something in Latex terminology and am I creating a command by using this word? How can I use it without creating any command?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show a tiny document with 'esquisser' in it that gives an error?  What error do you get.  Or is it just your editor which thinks the word is misspelt?

Comment: No it doesn't mean anything. What is the context in your document?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX Stack Exchange! I assume that by *"doesn't want me to write"* you mean that Latex displays an error. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4778) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for answerers to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hello ! thanks. So this is the message error I get : package inputenc error : unicode char/u8 not set up for use with LaTeX and then the sentence that doesn't work : Esquisser ici l’aspect de Napoléon, à cheval, sa lunette à la main, sur la hauteur de

Comment: It most certainly is not `Esquisser`'s fault; probably some of the `’` or `é` or `à`s throw LaTeX off (it might also be a weird space character or something). Can you add an MWE showing how you load `inputenc`? Check that your document is using the right character encoding.

Comment: And here is the context of my document : 

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchle]{babel}
\usepackage{frenchle}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
%%Figures
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

Comment: Is your document UTF8 encoded (check with a document editor that can display file encodings)?

Comment: this is weird because I have a very long document and that is the only line that causes a problem

Comment: If you want to know what exactly caused the problem: Delete the offending line; does the document compile? If it does not compile, the error lies elsewhere and only becomes apparent in that particular line. If it does, re-add small pieces of text (one word, for example) and recompile until the error occurs.

Comment: Ok I deleted the passage that caused a problem and now I have this error message : File ended wile scanning use of /@xdblarg

Comment: sorry \@xdblarg

Comment: I already had such problems, and usually it was due to a mix of utf8 text, text with another encoding and invisible characters. As ar as I remember, I solved the problem by copying the rest of the document to a brand new document,retyping the preamble and compiling this new document. If everything was OK, I retyped themissing line.

Comment: ok, I can try that, thank you ! but do you know what this last message error means ? Did you get it when you had that problem ? The error appears line 1, so I guess this is an error that goes for the whole document, and not for a specific part for the text

Comment: the error "file ended while ..." means that either a right-hand brace has been omitted, or the `\end{...}` member of a `\begin ... \end` pair is missing.  in this case, it's probably a missing brace.

Comment: @amélie you can put the code examples in _your question_ where they can be formatted rather than in comments. the `@xdblarg ` error means that latex was parsing an optional argument when it got to the end so you have `\zzz[` for some command `\zzz` with no closing `]`

Comment: Could it also be, that the mixing of input encodings with the use of uncommon space characters might yield the second error with `\@xdblarg` inside the encoding packages?

Comment: @barbara beeton and david carlisle: thank you very much ! I'll try to find the missing one then... okay, I'll put the code examples in my question next time, thanks for the information